# quiver3 returns vectors with incorrect length

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a set of vectors

```
t = [ -1    -1     0
       1    -1     0
       1     1     0
      -1     1     0 ]
```

those vectors form a square when plotted sequentially (head to tail)

I am using the `quiver3` instruction to obtain a plot of those vectors as follows:

```
quiver3(starts(:,1), starts(:,2), starts(:,3), t(:,1), t(:,2), t(:,3))
```

I calculated "starts" by cumulative sums of the matrix t and got the following result

```
starts = [ 0     0     0
          -1    -1     0
           0    -2     0
           1    -1     0]
```

All the values makes perfect sense and would give a square if plotted manually, but `quiver3` returned the following plot

[image]
[image]

Why aren't the vectors' heads touching the tails? how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `AutoScaleFactor` to **1**:

```
t = [...
    -1    -1     0
     1    -1     0
     1     1     0
    -1     1     0]

starts = [...
     0     0     0
    -1    -1     0
     0    -2     0
     1    -1     0]

quiver3(starts(:,1), starts(:,2), starts(:,3), t(:,1), t(:,2), t(:,3), ...
        'AutoScaleFactor',1)
```

---

[image]

It is set to **0.9** by default as a whole vector field would look a little messy otherwise.

---

Edit: see how this works for you:

```
 starts = [ 0 0 0; -13 12 0]
 t = [ -13 12 0; -1 2 0]

 quiver3(starts(:,1), starts(:,2), starts(:,3), t(:,1), t(:,2), t(:,3), 0)
 view(0,90)
```

The **0** defines the fixed scale factor, **0** means no scaling.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working; it worked perfectly with the above example, but then I tried starts= [   0     0     0;   -13    12     0] and
t=[  -13    12     0;     -1     2     0] and it failed again.

Comment: I just replaced ",AutoScaleFactor',1)" with ",0)" and it worked.